# Convert text to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, fetch

**What I want to achieve**
Inside React I want to fetch an HTML page with fetch and from the response i get I want to extract some data from a div with a class called "myDiv"

The data I am fetching are in an HTML format. Current I have this code which fetch the data and resolves the response in a text format.

```
fetch('/my/url')
  .then(response => response && response.text())
  .then(text => console.log('Do something that extract content in class "myDiv"));
```

Comment: Hi, can you please post a snippet of code of the React component you tried to write? So we can start from that to discuss.

Comment: You need to provide some snippet you tried, stack is not the platform to ask for solutions but to discuss issues and challenges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said above you can use DOMParser

```
const parser = new DOMParser(),
  dom = parser.parseFromString(text, "text/html");
```

then access the dom with habitual methods

```
let myDivContent = dom.querySelector('.myDiv').innerHTML;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I loved that this solution solved all my problems with so few lines.

Comment: You're welcome, but as in @leaf answer, the us of "const" instead of "let" is more appropriate because theses are static values.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this, its just plain old Vanila JS.

```js
//This is your fetched html string
let stringHTML = "<div> <h2>Some data</h2><div class='myDiv'> <h1> Test </h1> </div> </div>";
//Create temp element holder
let tempElement = document.createElement("div");
//Add fetched HTML to tempElement
tempElement.innerHTML = stringHTML;

//Now you can query it as it was a normal DOM element
let elementsWithClass = tempElement.getElementsByClassName("myDiv")

document.getElementById('root').appendChild(elementsWithClass[0]);
```

```html
<div id='root'> 

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser), which parses XML or HTML source code from a string into a DOM Document.

Ex:

```
const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString(stringContainingHTMLSource, "text/html");
// returns a HTMLDocument, which also is a Document.

const myDiv = doc.querySelector('.myDiv');
console.log(myDiv.innerText);
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML element in string format

```
var txt = JSON.stringify("<div class='c1'>Welcome</div>")
```

JSON.parse() convert string to html element ie [object Object]

`document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =  JSON.parse(txt)`